# MySQL not starting up after added log-bin - Master Replication

Tags: mysql, fedora, master-slave

I trying to set up master replication server. When I try to start/restart the server after added log-bin directory as following in my.cnf,

```
log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
```

the server is not starting up.

**MySQL status**

> mysqld.service - MySQL Server
>         Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled)
>         **Active: inactive (dead)** since Mon, 13 Jul 2015 17:46:47 +0800; 1s ago
>        Process: 14145 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>         CGroup: name=systemd:/system/mysqld.service

But after I changed the log-bin as following (without folder path)

```
log-bin = mysql-bin.log
```

the server is running successfully.

**MySQL status**

> mysqld.service - MySQL Server
>         Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled)
>         **Active: active (running)** since Mon, 13 Jul 2015 17:47:43 +0800; 2s ago
>       Main PID: 15272 (mysqld_safe)
>         CGroup: name=systemd:/system/mysqld.service
>             ├ 15272 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysq...
>             └ 15615 /usr/libexec/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/...

**Update**

From **mysqld.log** :

> /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 2)

But my mysql-bin.index by default at

> /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.index

Could anyone please help me out as I just start to learn master-slave replication? Do I need to create a folder name mysql and change the permission to mysql and put in log directory or how I can make sure it locates my mysql-bin.index file correctly?

Comment: whats the error message in error logs.

Comment: Im not sure how to check the error messages. I just use the mysql service status

Comment: there must be error log file in data directory , tail the file and check last error message

Comment: @AmanAggarwal how to check the error message

Comment: Try Commenting the #datadir= and try restarting the mysqld

Comment: @chandran may I know what is the purpose doing this?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html

Comment: Does anyone encountered this kind of problem before?

Comment: @AmanAggarwal from the mysqld.log its shows that File '/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 2). Do I need to create a folder name as mysql?

Comment: @chandran  from the mysqld.log its shows that File '/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 2). Do I need to create a folder name as mysq and keep in log directoryl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution. Not sure whether I did it in a right way.

After searched about **(Errcode: 2)**, found that it is indicate that the file or directory does not exist. So I have created the folder named as mysql and added in log directory (Logged in as root user). When I try to restart the server, it gives me another error:

> /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13)

**Errcode: 13** indicates permission denied. So I have change the ownership from root to mysql :

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
```

I restart the server and it runs successfully.

Answer (score 3):

If there is an error in path access related to data and logs of mysql it will call the default /var/lib/mysql and /var/log/mysql. To ovveride mysql log file path do the following.

1. create new path
2. make the path with ownership of mysql user
   example - sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /mnt/mysql/logs
3. pass the path to apparmor to read this directory.
   file location -  /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld

   content

   ## Allow log file access

   ```
    /mnt/mysql/logs/ r,

    /mnt/mysql/logs/** rw,
   ```

**Note:** if apparmor has not correct path then it will give issue of permission that confuses with simple chown and chmod

Comment: apparmor was definitely the cause in my case - thanks ravi

Comment: apparmor also was the issue in my case !